# Zoom при с работе с Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Пытаюсь разобраться с работой с координатами, вычисляю свои координаты и перемещаю камеру, все верно, но если добавить к точке перемещения zoom, то камера оказывается в океане.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
    }else{
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,1,locationListener);
    }
```

Перемещение камеры

```
private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        if (location != null)
        {
            Log.d("TAG", "Широта="+location.getLatitude());
            Log.d("TAG", "Долгота="+location.getLongitude());
            MoveCamera(location);
        }
    }
```

И сам метод

```
public void MoveCamera(Location curr) {
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(curr.getAltitude(),curr.getLongitude()),20));
}
```

Comment: Проблемы с доступом к координатам? Поменяйте `getAltitude()` на `getLatitude()`, чтобы получилось `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(curr.getLatitude(),curr.getLongitude()),20));` :) И не вижу смысла ради одной строки создавать метод, даже если он будет дублироваться)

Comment: Действительно, спасибо, не заметил данную мелочь